# Typescript not enforcing types

Tags: javascript, typescript2.0, typechecking

I have this very simple code:

```
let viewsDictionary: { [key: string]: Object } = {
    abc: {}
};
type ViewName = keyof typeof viewsDictionary;

let result: ViewName;

result = "category";
```

TypeScript version 2.2.2 does not complain that result can only have the value "abc". Why?

Comment: Are you sure you mean `Object` with an uppercase `O`?

Answer (score 2):

You are explicitly giving `viewsDictionary` type `{ [key: string]: Object }`. The fact that you are assigning a compatible value does not change its type and so `typeof viewsDictionary` stays `{ [key: string]: Object }` and `keyof` are any string.

You can verify that by assigning

```
viewsDictionary = { category: {} };
```

which works fine as well.

Just remove the explicit type declaration, so TS infers the type itself and it will work as expected:

```
let viewsDictionary = {
    abc: {}
};
type ViewName = keyof typeof viewsDictionary;

let result: ViewName;

result = "category"; error
```

now complains that Type '"category"' is not assignable to type '"abc"'.

**Update:**

You can also specify the type explicitly (from comments):

```
let viewsDictionary: {abc: {}} = {
    abc: {},
    def: {}, // error 
};
type ViewName = keyof typeof viewsDictionary;

let result: ViewName;

result = "def"; // still error
```

This will complain when you add another key to viewsDictionary that Type `'{ abc: {}; def: {}; }'` is not assignable to type `'{ abc: {}; }'`

Comment: I thought as much; the technical term for this is type widening. But if I do as you say, problem now is that viewsDictionary itself can have values of any type. I want to ensure that the values of viewsDictionary  are all of a specific type, and also create a type off of its keys.